# How to seamlessly dismiss a modal and push a new ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, modalviewcontroller

In our chat application we have a list of active conversations (ChatsVC) which has a button to present a modal (CreateChatsVC). This modal allows the user to create a new conversation.

When the user has selected which users to chat with we want the modal (CreateChatsVC) to dismiss and the conversation view (ConversationVC) to be pushed onto the underlying (ChatsVC) WITHOUT actually seeing the underlying ChatsVC in the transition.

What we were doing up until now in the CreateChatVC was:

```
[rootPane dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
[rootPane.navigationController pushViewController:conversationVC animated:NO];
```

However we noticed that on iOS 8 this caused some visual artifacts, namely when the user went back to the ChatsVC from the ConversationVC the table was scrolled halfway down but as soon as you touched the screen it would instantly snap back to the top. After changing our transition code to the following:

```
[rootPane dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [rootPane.navigationController pushViewController:conversationVC animated:NO];
}];
```

These visual artefacts disappeared but now there is a split second where the user can see the underlying ChatsVC which is undesirable.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better alternative to this transition, or suggestions as to why this tableView scroll issue appears only on iOS8?

A sample user flow would be:

push ChatsVC -> click to present CreateChatsVC modal -> select user to chat with -> dismiss CreateChatsVC modal and instantly push ConversationVC

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it work for you if the flow is changed to this?   push ChatsVC -> click to push Conversation VC -> automatically present user selection on viewDidAppear of Conversation VC -> if user is selected, return to Conversation VC, otherwise pop to ChatsVC.

Comment: You need `setViewControllers:animated:` of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Have you tried unwind (exit) segues?

Comment: Have you tried delegation to dismiss your modal view. Subclass your `UINavigationController` to be the delegate, present and dismiss the modal from there. When dismissing, push the new chat view first then dismiss the modal.

Comment: @sixthcent this is a possibility but would require redesign (which has to get approved first)

Comment: @Cy-4AH this is not feasible as our application uses a "rootviewcontroller" concept where everything is pushed and popped to the root. Using `setViewControllers:animated:` would require editing the full view stack which is undesirable.

Comment: @Razvan we're not using storyboards in our application

Comment: A slightly better flow is actually this:  push ChatsVC->click to present another navigation vc with user selection vc as the root->after user selection, push conversation vc to the presented navigation stack->when done, just dismiss the presented navigation stack to go back to ChatsVC.  If design cannot be changed, I would suggest trying the dismissal and push without animation and see if they avoid the delay. Needs some experimenting.

Comment: @alexgophermix, you will just push next view without poping to previous, but previous will be remove from view stack.